# How can I implement joi-password-complexity in Joi validation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passwords, joi

I want to enforce password complexity by using the joi-password-complexity package when users register.

https://github.com/kamronbatman/joi-password-complexity

I tried but I got the following error:

> (node:14872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError
>   [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid schema content:
>   (password.$_root.alternatives)

This is the code I'm using:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require("joi");
const passwordComplexity = require("joi-password-complexity");

const complexityOptions = {
  min: 5,
  max: 250,
  lowerCase: 1,
  upperCase: 1,
  numeric: 1,
  symbol: 1,
  requirementCount: 2,
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    minlenght: 1,
    maxlength: 55,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024,
    required: true
  }
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(1).max(55).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
    password: passwordComplexity(complexityOptions) // This is not working
  }
  return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}

exports.User = User;
exports.validate = validateUser;
```

I also tried to follow this example: https://forum.codewithmosh.com/d/215-joi-password-complexity-problem but it seems outdated since the "new" keyword will throw another error (not a constructor).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't reproduce your exact error, but I had the thing working this way:

- `@hapi/joi: ^17.1.0` (latest at the time of the writing, also works with 16.1.8)
- `joi-password-complexity: ^4.0.0` (latest as well)

Code:

```js
function validateUser(user) {
  // no change here
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(1).max(55).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
    password: passwordComplexity(complexityOptions)
  });
  // note that we call schema.validate instead of Joi.validate
  // (which doesn't seem to exist anymore)
  return schema.validate(user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have the proper versions installed. I copy pasted your code but I keep getting the error when I send the request: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid schema content:
    at new AssertionError (internal/assert.js:269:11)`

Comment: Ah I also wrapped your `schema` in a `Joi.object`, forgot about that. And it works, like [here](https://repl.it/repls/LongConventionalPress). So maybe the issue doesn't come from Joi's schema but from Mongoose's?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I was using `const Joi = require("joi");` instead of `const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');`. What's the difference?

Comment: Not sure there's really a difference, but `joi-password-complexity`'s internal `require` may be resolved to a _different_ object (`require` caches already-resolved packages), which may cause weird behaviors... I can't see any other reason, and it's highly hypothetical!

Answer (score 4):

Here is how i solved the issue:
if You are using joi@14.3.1 or older then install joi-password-complexity@2.0.1 then try this code:

```
User.js model

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require("joi");
const PasswordComplexity = require("joi-password-complexity");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = {
    name: Joi.string()
      .min(3)
      .max(50)
      .required(),
    email: Joi.string()
      .email()
      .max(255)
      .required(),
    password:  new PasswordComplexity({
    min: 8,
    max: 25,
    lowerCase: 1,
    upperCase: 1,
    numeric: 1,
    symbol: 1,
    requirementCount: 4
  });
  };
  return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}

module.exports.validate = validateUser;
module.exports.User = User;
```

This will validate password complexity but for making password REQUIRED you have to validate it in your route...

```
Users.js route

const _ = require("lodash");
const express = require("express");
const { User, validate } = require("../models/user");

const router = express.Router();

//POST
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  //
  if (!req.body.password) return res.status(400).send("Password is required..");

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered..");

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password"]));
  await user.save();
  res.send(_.pick(user, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please pay attention this is a '@hapi/joi' dependent not the previous 'joi' version!

Comment: I think this the codes form from Mosh's Nodejs course (Vidly API). Thanks for the solution though. This is what I'm exactly looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6901801/mr-spshuvo Yes it's Mosh code

Answer (score 3):

I had to add `.default` to import the function that returns the Joi object. Using Joi 17.3.0 and joi-password-complexity 5.0.1, this is what worked for me:

```js
const passwordComplexity = require('joi-password-complexity').default;

const schema = Joi.object({
  email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
  password: passwordComplexity().required(),
});
```

Comment: Excellent, I have reported the problem to the author, here: https://github.com/kamronbatman/joi-password-complexity/issues/37

Answer (score 2):

Since the passwordComplexity() returns a Joi object, you can write `required` in a fluent way. Thus, you don't have to write extra validation in the router.

```js
function validateUser(user) {
  // no change here
  const schema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(1).max(55).required(),
    email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
    password: passwordComplexity(complexityOptions).required()
  });
  // note that we call schema.validate instead of Joi.validate
  // (which doesn't seem to exist anymore)
  return schema.validate(user);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Versions used of Joi and JPC:
├── ...
├── joi@17.2.1
├── joi-password-complexity@4.2.1

The validation function must be updated to fit with the new updated version of JOI. joi.validate() is no longer supported in Joi v16+

```
   const Joi = require("joi");
   const passwordComplexity = require("joi-password-complexity");

   function validateUser(user) {
      const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password: passwordComplexity(complexityOptions),
      });
      return schema.validate(user); // NOT >> Joi.validate(user, schema);  !!!!!
    }
```

and the **complexityOptions** can be something like:

```
const complexityOptions = {
  min: 5,
  max: 1024,
  lowerCase: 1,
  upperCase: 1,
  numeric: 1,
  symbol: 1,
  requirementCount: 4,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another way is [Regex](https://regex101.com/)

```
const joi = require("joi");

const strongPasswordRegex = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/;
const stringPassswordError = new Error("Password must be strong. At least one upper case alphabet. At least one lower case alphabet. At least one digit. At least one special character. Minimum eight in length")

const schema = joi.object().keys({
    username: joi.string().required().min(4).max(15),
    password: joi.string().regex(strongPasswordRegex).error(stringPassswordError).required()
});

const notValid = schema.validate({ username: "MHamzaRajput", password: "Admin@admin123" }).error;

if (notValid) {
    console.log(notValid.message);
} else {
    console.log("payload validated successfully");
}
```